# Let$~${$ f_1 , f_2 , .. , f_n$} be functions lineary indepenedante in $ I$ Prove that every Subset ...

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let$~${$ f_1 , f_2 , .. , f_n$} be functions lineary indepenedante in $ I$ Prove that every Subset of the group is also lineary independante in $ I $ ( interval).

**how do i prove such claim with differential equations ? say with the wronsekian** .

here is my prof ( might not be right ) :

lets suppose that there exist subset such that

without the loss of generality {$ f_1 , f_2 , .. , f_k$} , $k<n$  dependant.

so $ \sum_i^k \alpha_i^*f_i = 0$ such that $\alpha_1^* ,\alpha_2^*,\alpha_3^*,...,\alpha_k^* $ not all $0$ ,suppose at least $\alpha_1^* \not= 0$.

so there exist $\alpha_1^* ,\alpha_2^*,\alpha_3^*,...,\alpha_k^*,0,0,0,0,...,0 $ not all $0$ such that :

$ \sum_1^n \alpha_if_i = \sum_1^k \alpha_i^*f_i + 0f_{k+1}+0f_{k+2}+...+0f_{n} = 0$

so its lineary dependant but we know that its not. QED

Comment: Your proof is correct.